# Как установить SSL сертификат на домен из присланных ключей от reg.ru?

Tags: ssl

Занимаюсь установкой SSL сертификата для домена. Заказали сертификат и нам пришло письмо "Данные для установки ssl сертификата для домена prostokna.ru"

В теле письма находится 5 ключей:
- Ваш сертификат предоставлен ниже
- Корневой сертификат
- Промежуточный сертификат
- Запрос на получение сертификата
- Сохраните приватный ключ на локальном компьютере

Я не совсем понимаю, какой ключ что означает.

На стороне сервера выполняю команды:
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out mydomain.csr -keyout private.key

Далее
openssl x509 -req -in mydomain.csr -signkey private.key -out server.crt

Запускаю проект и у меня все работает, но естественно "Подключение не защищено"

Пробывал заменять содержимое файлов файлами из письма, но явно делаю что то не то.
Подскажите пж.

Comment: Начнём с того, что если **приватный** ключ лежит **на почте**, это это откровенная утечка, ключ **скомпрометирован**, безопасности больше нет, использовать его нельзя и остаётся только выбросить это всё в мусорку

Comment: По теме вопроса непонятно, что вам непонятно. Для запуска чего-то там у вас, видимо, нужны сертификат и приватный ключ, вот и используйте файлы из письма вместо файлов из openssl. В чём конкретно затруднения?

Comment: Приватный ключ в теле письма это сильно. По делу. Просто прописываете где надо пути к корневому сертификату и приватному ключу.

Comment: Сертификат предоставил reg.ru... Они кинули почтой...

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален? Если да, то на какой сервер нужно поставить сертификат - Apache HTTP, nginx или какой-то другой?